# How do I create more progressbars based upon a certain criteria

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I've been wanting to create something like CoreTemp
[image]

As you can see at the bottom it has 4 cores it's checking the temperature of.
And it will adapt depending on how many cores you have. How does that work? How does it create new *slots* depending on how many cores you have? How would I do this using WinForms and not WPF?

Comment: You're getting marked down because you're not asking a direct question.  It sounds more like you're asking, how do I write an application.  I'm not saying you mean it that way... Try being more specific and showing the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically add controls to a panel. You can use `TableLayoutPanel` and dynamically add rows with controls to it.

```
TableLayoutPanel layoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
layoutPanel.ColumnCount = 5; //Core Name, Temperature, Low, High, Load
layoutPanel.RowCount = 1;

// Adding controls to columns
layoutPanel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Core #0" }, 1, 0);
//... and so on

// Adding more rows 
layoutPanel.RowCount = layoutPanel.RowCount + 1;
```